# Clone a hard drive except for one partition?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone

My existing hard drive is 500GB with 60GB of programs, operating system files, etc. on one partition, and lots of data on a second partition. I want to clone the C drive to a new SSD I bought, but I don't want to clone my data on the D drive.

I have tried EZ Gig IV, but it only clones whole drives instead of just the partitions you want.

What are my options?

Comment: if you're asking for a recommendation on a piece of software that can do this, its considered off topic.

Comment: No he isn't. He is asking for instructions on how to do it. His question is perfectly fine. It's too bad I only know the answer in *Nix, otherwise I would have posted it . Sorry, posfan12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get partedmagic burned to a CD/DVD
connect both hard drive and SSD with power off.
boot from CD/DVD
launch **partition editor**
Use the drop down in the upper right hand corner to select your old hard drive.
Right click on the C: partition and select **copy**
Use the drop down in the upper right hand corner to select your SSD.
Right click and do a paste.

```
 If you get an error the partition table does not exist.
```

the menu across the top has the option to create a partition table.  As all current SSD are below 2tb I suggest you use the **msdos** kind of partition table.

If you previously got the partition table error you should now have one and be able to **right click** and paste.

After that you may resize the partition on the SSD to your liking.

Click the **apply** button and wait

and wait some more.

Right click on the partition on the SSD and **Manage flags** then check **boot** flag on.

Reboot the system and go into your BIOS

Change the boot order to boot from your SSD.

Then boot your pc from the SSD.

If everything is in order you may now go back and delete the old partition from your hard drive.  Inside **Windows 7** and above the **Disk Management** tool has the ability to delete non system, non boot, and non swap/hibernation file partitions.  In addition, under the same restrictions, it can also resize a partition.